# Intermittent selenium failures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec, capybara, circleci

I'm having intermittent build issues on our CI that consistently succeed locally. We had our master build succeed but rebuild fails (without cache clear or any changes). The failures are only on our js-driven feature specs, the others succeed consistently for both CI and dev.

Error: `Net::ReadTimeout`

Partial Stack:

- Rails 4.1.4
- RSpec 3.0
- Capybara (2.4.1, 2.5, and master)
- selenium-webdriver 2.45.0

Failed fix attempts:

- Updating capybara and/or selenium
- Revert first merge we noticed the errors
- Clearing build cache
- Updating dev group and/or test group gems

Any help is hugely appreciated!

Comment: Post on CI's forum: https://discuss.circleci.com/t/intermittent-selenium-failures/194

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up solving this one. It's partially due to an error on our part and partially due to a selenium bug.

Steps to reproduce:

1. `visit /path/to/page`
2. `alert("whatever")` {don't close it}
3. call `visit /path/to/page` again

Any subsequent pages selenium loads will still have the alert box open, thus most matchers will break.